# 3d time series gnuplot GIF

Tags: 3d, gnuplot, gif

I have a function z(x,y,t) and I'd like to animate the time evolution in a GIF. I saved the space data into 3 column text file of the form

x y z

with file names 1.txt, 2.txt, ..., 100.txt

I'd like a 2d GIF with the z column colored as a temperature. From what I've read this should be possible but I'm having trouble implementing it as I've only done basic plotting in gnuplot. Something like this

http://www.gnuplotting.org/animation-gif/

but with all the data files I have. I've spend the better part of a day looking for a solution with no luck. My apologies if this is already done somewhere else.

Comment: What are the concrete problems you're having? There are several examples about animated gifs with gnuplot here on SO. In short: `set terminal gif animate delay 100; set output 'animation.gif'; do for [i=1:100]{ plot sprintf('%d.txt', i) with image notitle }`.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I think most of the examples I saw used functions versus data so I was having trouble with that. I was also a little confused about the "sprintf" command. I think it makes sense now. I tried your example and I'm getting the message    "warning:skipping unreadable file" "no data in plot" But since I know the text file exists and has the data it must be a directory issue, right?

Comment: Right, type `pwd` in the interactive gnuplot shell to see in which directory you are working.

Comment: I am in the folder where the files are "...\Battery\movie". I put the files in a folder called movie btw.

Comment: If you want to notify someone (e.g. me) with a comment, use e.g. @Christoph. Only the original poster gets always notified. If you need `splot` or `plot` depends on your requirements and your data structure. (regular grid or scattered data, interpolation wanted, surface or map plot etc).